# Cambiar de pagina en proyecto WPF en C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy comenzando a trabajar con proyectos WPF en C# y estoy diseñando la aplicación con blend, pero no encuentro la manera de cambiar de pagina.
Tengo un login y al darle click en entrar, como puedo cambir de pagina en el mismo frame.

Comment: Hola, comparte tu codigo de lo que llevas hasta el momento.

Comment: No tengo nada, voy comenzado una aplicacion de escitorio con WPF en VS 2017.
Tengo el diseño de un login y nada mas.

No se que tipo de clase o pagina debo de crear para poder cambir de diseño  el frame y me quite el login y me muestre los demas forularios.

Comment: Como quieres trabajar, todo en una sola ventana? o tienes varias ventanas para llamarla despues de tu login?

Comment: Antes trabajaba con Java y en estos casos cambiaba de panales en el Frame principal, esperaba hacer los mismo en este lenguaje.

Pero como ya batalle bastante, ya cualquier manera me sirve, ya sea en una sola ventana, o mandar diferentes ventanas.

En proyectos UWP se usa el codigo  

Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));

pero en WPF no funciona y espero algo pareido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para moverte de una pagina a otro debes usar el `NavigationService`

[Información general sobre navegación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/navigation-overview#navigation-hosts)

entonces podrias hacer algo como ser

```
void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("AnotherPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Para navegar un frame es la misma tecnica

[WPF Navigation](http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation)

[Working with WPF Frame using C# and XAML](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/using-xaml-frame-in-wpf857/)

solo que lo aplicas al frame

```
Frame1.Navigate(new System.Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Comment: No me funciono, eh leído y creo que eso es para paginas web, la mía es un aplicación de escritorio.

Comment: pero las ventanas heredan de NavigationWindow ? https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0f100d/navigation-window-based-application-in-wpf/

Comment: Al heredar de NavigtionWindow, me deja de reconocer los componentes de XAML, al darme error en InitializeComponent();

Comment: edite la repsuesta agregando el detalle del frame, pero ojo que lo que navegas son pages, valida que el xaml tenga <Page> y no <Window>